# How do I see source code with comments?

Tags: r, comments

I want to view the R source code with any comments included, to see how the author of the package is running his code, but I am unsure what command to use to see it.  In particular, I am trying to see the source code for the `bgp()` function in the R `tgp` package.  So far I have tried

```
library(tgp)
tgp::bgp
tgp:::bgp
```

but each of these commands shows only the source code with the comments stripped away.

Comment: have you tried `tgp:::bgp` or `getAnywhere("bgp")` ?

Comment: Yes I have.  I'll add output from running that command to show why its a problem.

Comment: I am totally befuddled. This looks exactly like the source code for the `bgp` function to me.  What do you expect to see here that you're not seeing ???  What's missing ??

Comment: One more wild guess before I have to go.  Perhaps you see that the 'meat' of the function is embodied in a further call to the `tgp` function.  To see that, try `tgp:::tgp`.  Other than that, I can't guess what you're looking for.

Comment: It seems to me that this question has been reworded from the apparently confusing original to a perfectly sensible question. Shouldn't it be opened up again?
It gave me exactly the answer I was looking for

Comment: @Anton. Agree. Voted to reopen. The question was not really how to find or recommend some external source but rather how to investigate further a specific code source that had already been identified.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That is offering you the parsed version of the code, but it strips out all the comments. The package sources are here: http://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/tgp_2.4-9.tar.gz

The bgp code is in btgp.R in the R directory.

The general approach to finding the original source to a package on CRAN is to go to: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/available_packages_by_name.html

Comment: I guess I should have been more specific in what I wanted.  But this is exactly what I needed.  Thanks!

Comment: @BabakP , would you be willing to edit your question so that it reflects what you really wanted?  (i.e., source code with intact comments) ...