# RStudio: Debug function: See source with comments

Tags: r, debugging, rstudio

When debugging a function (from a loaded package) in RStudio using for example `debug()`, a version of the source code that has been automatically parsed by R is shown in the editor instead of the original source code. For example whole line comments and empty lines have been removed. However, comments and whitespace can make the code easier to read and understand.

Is there any way to make the debugger show the original source code while debugging?

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18005488/how-do-i-see-source-code-with-comments) 
question is related, but only concerns viewing the original source code, not if there is a way to do it while using the RStudio debugger.

Comment: Have a look at `browser()`

Comment: I don't think that helps me. I don't see that `browser()` helps me view and step through the original source code from a function in a package. `debug()` calls `browser()` when entering the function marked for debugging by the `debug()` call, [see first few slides here](http://www.math.ncu.edu.tw/~chenwc/R_note/reference/debug/Rdebug.pdf)

Comment: `browser` let you go into your functions, yes it is not what you want for packages